# Saving strings containing <> characters with javascript

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a C# MVC site where I can save code snippets. I use a textarea to paste in my code. It fails when I try to save certain characters. I'm using jqueryUI.

This is the function that saves my textarea to the DB where snippetAdd is the ID of my textarea:

```
function addSnippet() {

    $("#newSnippet").show();
    var myStuff = { snippetCode: $('#snippetAdd').val(), lexiconId: $('#lexiconId').val(), snippetDesc: $('#snippetDescAdd').val() };
    var aURL = "/Lexicon/addSnippet";
    $.post(aURL, myStuff, function(data) { parseMessage(data); }, 'json');
}
```

For example, if I past in and try to save the following, without the single quotes it fails:

'<'some code'>'

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when "it fails"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the problem is stemming from the fact that you aren't encoding your input. (You didn't elaborate on the error so this is a best guess.) Anyways, try doing this with all of your input:

```
encodeURI($('#snippetAdd').val())
```

This HTML-encodes your string, replacing special characters with their encoded equivalents. You will of course have to decode your string on the server side to reconstitute the original code entered in the field.

Answer (score 0):

@LeviBotelho has the correct approach. However, you also have the option to tell MVC not to validate the incoming data by annotating the controller:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
{...}
```

Note: This is not the safest approach as it leaves your server open to potential script injection attacks. It should be used if you trust your users and perform the encoding immediately server side.